# How I can add FontAwesome icon class in dropdown menu to my website

Tags: php, font-awesome

How I can add Font Awesome icons in a dropdown menu to my website? I bought PHP code from CodeCanyon. Here is link to this page: https://codecanyon.net/item/biolink-boost-instagram-bio-linking/20740546 [instead of writing should be dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNnHh.png)

Comment: your question is not clear for me. can you explain more with or without some code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNnHh.png Here in this image shown, instead of writing, here should be dropdown menu with icons

Answer (score 1):

if you want add icon to select box. you can add [select2](https://select2.org/) and add icon to your select box. in hear get icon from `data-icon` set it to your selection box when select2 initializing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Select-Box</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <select id="select-icon" name="vehicle" id="vehicle">
    <option value="bicycle" data-icon="fa-bicycle">bicycle</option>
    <option value="car" data-icon="fa-car">car</option>
    <option value="van" data-icon="fa-shuttle-van">van</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    function formatText (icon) {
        return $('<span><i class="fas ' + $(icon.element).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text + '</span>');
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-icon').select2({
            width:'50%',
            templateSelection: formatText,
            templateResult: formatText
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want add it nav bar with dropdown you can add icon before your text with span tag  `<span class="fas fa-bicycle"></span>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <span class="fas fa-bicycle"></span> &nbsp;bicycle</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fas fa-car"></span>&nbsp;car</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fas fa-shuttle-van"></span>&nbsp;van</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```